# Why two 2nd order filters have different roll off?

Tags: frequency, active-filter, frequency-response

[image: Butter-worth filter design 1] [image: Butter-worth filter design 2]

I have designed these two butterworth filter for 1.5k cutoff frequency. what it surprising me that roll off of first design is more than roll off of second design. According to me both are 2nd order hence it should be 40dB/dec for both.
Kindly explain or give some hint that where should i look at.

Comment: Show the graphs of the difference please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically these two filters don't have the same characteristic.

- The [Sallen key filter](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPstool.php) (lower circuit) has a theoretical 3dB frequency of 2340 Hz and a Q of 0.5.
- The [MFB filter](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPttool.php) (top circuit) has a theoretical 3dB frequency of 1489 Hz and a Q of 0.703.

Why would you expect these to look the same: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply sir, as much the cutoff frequency is concerned, i have verified both by their respective spice models, and i have used P-spice for simulation. I have found both cut-off were in range of 1.45-1.6 KHz. But I will look into quality factor, as it is one of the main factors to shape the response of filter. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered that an LMX324 has a maximum supply voltage of 7V - you are running it at 10V if your schematic is to be believed. Also, check that you have correctly put the actual circuit values into the schematic in your question.

Comment: To post question here I draw circuit on partsim as currenty i am accessing internet from office PC. actual product used is LM324;http://www.ti.com/product/LM324

Comment: You don't help yourself by giving incorrect information.

Comment: Yes i should have checked, I thought them to be of same series. anyway thanks.

Comment: I didn`t check the mentioned Q-values. However, if they are correct (and different) both circuits will exhibit a different charcteristics in the vicinity of the 3-dB- frequency. More than that, the low-Q filter (Q=0.5) is NOT a Butterworth-filter. However, far above the 3dB frequency both filters will have a 40dB/dec roll-off. In general, filter response does NOT depend on the chosen topology (Sallen-Key or MFB or...).

Comment: @LvW I totally agree - at a significantly higher frequency it should be 40 dB/decade but, I'm also wondering how the MFB copes at high frequencies compared to the SK filter given that the op-amp is a crappy LM324 (not LMX324)? Different topologies have different responses when the op-amp runs out of steam at HF!!

Comment: Yes - if compared with S&K structures, MFB has lower sensitivity against parts tolerances but a higher sensitivity against the real opamp gain prpperties. For S&K it is just the opposite.

Comment: @LvW I suspect this may have something to do with the OP's observations!

Comment: I don`t think so because of the low pole frequency of app. 1.5kHz only. At first, both pole-Qs are different and, more than that, I suppose he has measured the "roll-off" to close to the pole frequency.